# Python, Kivy. Textinput thousands separator

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I need `thousands separator` (*for example: 1 000 000*) in a `kivy TextInput` for a better readability while typing.

Edit:
Here is a short example where the `label` shows space separators and I need the same result in a `TextInput` while typing. I guess I have to use filtering in `MyTextInput class` but I really don't know where to start. Could you help me to solve this problem?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Calc>:
    first_num:first_num 
    second_num:second_num
    result:result
    
    MyTextInput:
        id: first_num      
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.2, "y": 0.7}
    
    MyTextInput:
        id: second_num       
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "y": 0.7}       
    
    Button:
        text: "R E S U L T"
        
        on_release:
            root.multiplication()
        
        size_hint: 0.3, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "y": 0.4}
    
    Label:
        id: result       
        
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "y": 0.2}        

    """
)

class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    input_filter = ObjectProperty('int', allownone=True)


class Calc(FloatLayout):
    first_num = ObjectProperty()
    second_num = ObjectProperty()
    result = ObjectProperty()

    def multiplication(self):
        x = int(self.first_num.text)
        y = int(self.second_num.text)

        self.result.text = '{:,}'.format(int(x*y)).replace(",", " ")


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calc()

myApp().run()
```

Comment: Did you try with string formatting ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but it doesn't work or I miss something (on a label I use this: `'{:,}'.format(int(x)).replace(",", " ")`

Comment: That should've worked depending on the implementation. Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Minimal code is added to my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the [`insert_text`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.insert_text) method of `TextInput` object in order to get expected result as,

```py
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.input_filter = 'int' # Set value using the default property.


    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo = False):
        # Override this super-class method.
        if not substring.isdigit(): # Eliminates non digit character.
            return
        else:
            cc, cr = self.cursor
            text = self._lines[cr]
            new_text = text[:cc] + substring + text[cc:]
            int_str = new_text.replace(" ", "") # Removing any inbetween space.
            new_text = '{:,d}'.format(int(int_str)).replace(",", " ") # Here insert seperator.
            super().insert_text(substring, from_undo = from_undo)

            self._set_line_text(cr, new_text) # Super-class method.
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt : setattr(self, "cursor", (cc+2, cr))) # Advances the cursor.
```

Also you need some modifications in method `multiplication`.

```py
    def multiplication(self):
        # First remove any inbetween space.
        num_text_1 = self.first_num.text.replace(" ", "")
        num_text_2 = self.second_num.text.replace(" ", "")
        if num_text_1 and num_text_2: # Non empty values.
            x = int(num_text_1)
            y = int(num_text_2)

            self.result.text = '{:,}'.format(int(x*y)).replace(",", " ")
        else:
            self.result.text = "" # Or, any other message.
```